# Receiving Critical error from infopath forms services

Tags: 2007, infopath, publishing

Recently published SharePoint 2007 via ISA server.   Everything seems to working okay  other than while approving workflows.

receiving Critical  error from InfoPath forms services

> " An error occurred submitting this form to the web server, the form
>   will now be closed.     Click start over to load a new copy of the
>   form. If this error persists, contact the support team for the web
>   site.  Click close to exit this message. "

Kindly help me to sort this issue out